# Failed assertion: line 4429 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true. while showing BottomModalSheet

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

I'm getting this error while showing Bottom Modal Sheet code of Bottom Sheet method :

```
  _showMoreOptions(BuildContext context) {
  return showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context) {
  return Container(
    height: 250,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: colorWhite
    ),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text("Hello")
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
 });
}
```

The button I'm calling this method :

```
   InkWell(
      onTap: () {
      print("call");
      _showMoreOptions(context);
    },
      child: Icon(
      MaterialIcons.subtitles,
      color: colorFDEF50,
   )),
```

If you have any solution I'd be thankful :)